# System.Text.Json Schema Validation

Tags: json, validation, schema, jsonschema, system.text.json

Does System.Text.Json expose any methods to validate Json schemas? I have looked at their documentation but it appears that this is still tbd.

Comment: Not as of .NET 7, and nothing is currently scheduled.  See [`[System.Text.Json]` Json Schemas Support #29887](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29887), which is currently "Open" with priority "Wishlist" and milestone "Future".  Some 3rd party tools are promoted there as alternatives.

Comment: I am trying to avoid Newtonsoft.Json - as it's not going to be viable in a CI environment where more than 10 hits for schema validation are highly likely. Other 3rd party tools are less desirable. Would prefer to stay with System.Text.Json

Answer (score 3):

you can take a look to the current JSON Schema .NET implementations here:

https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validator-dotnet

Comment: On that list, only JsonSchema.Net supports System.Text.Json.

Comment: I not had much luck with trying to validate json schemas using System.Text.Json. By JsonSchema.Net are you referring to json-everything? If that is the case, then could you refer to some documentation how to validate schemas using that package in C#? I posted this question the other day with some sample code - but have not had any luck/response yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75035777/json-not-validating-against-json-schema-c-sharp-draft-6-openapi-3-0